# Highchart , how to remove the margins, inside the chart? Creating a 100% zoom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have the following chart, and I need to delete the default internal margin (market with red boxes)
[image]

I havent been able to do so

This is my current code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        margin: [0,0,0,0],
    },
    title: {text: null},
        legend: { enabled: false },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/41z9qk2m/

This is the doc page

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

xAxis ,and yAxis min max
as per

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max